# Date conversion: From LINQ to JSON to Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, json, datetime, formatting

In short, between my API controller and the Javascript that uses the result, a Date is converted into a lovely `NaN`

My question is where, and perhaps how, one recommends I fix this long chain.

**Step 1: Retrieve object from database with LINQ**

```
return _dbContext.Points.Where(
    point => point.AccountId == account.AccountId)
    .OrderBy(point => point.EarnedOn).ToList();
```

It seems unreasonable to make any changes here. The model specifies a DateTime field, so we really don't have any interaction with strings here.

**Step 2: API controller sends response**

```
var points = _pointRepository.GetByUserName(userName);
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, points);
```

Could I specify here how to parse the date? Would that make sense to even handle on the server side? I suppose I could loop through all the objects and set them manually, like so:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < points.Count(); i++ )
 {
     points.ElementAt(i).EarnedOn =  points.ElementAt(i).EarnedOn.ToUniversalTime();
 }
```

But talk about multiple enumerations!

**Step 3: Client parses JSON data to a JS Object, then parses the Date from the string to an int**
*Greatly shortened for readability*

```
var points = JSON.parse(response);
for(i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    var date = Date.parse(points[i].EarnedOn);
```

At this point, there's only so much I can do.  I've already converted the date into a string at the end of step2, and the browser I'm targeting simply doesn't know how to work with C#'s default `DateTime.toString` format (I assume that's what is being sent). In some browsers it works, in others I get the `NaN`.

Sorry for the long explanation, but again if anyone could point out where and how they would apply the fix, I'd appreciate it.

====Update====

The browser in question is Android's stock browser. I've tested this both on my phone and in a BlueStacks emulator. Both are up to date, and it works in neither. It does work in Chrome.

The JSON output of the time (cutting out all the other data) appears as follows:

```
"EarnedOn":"2012-05-10T00:00:00"
```

Comment: This seems odd. What browser *are* you targeting, and what does the JSON actually look like? Can you post that? At least the date representation.

Comment: @aquinas Updated my question to answer yours

Comment: [This chart](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) shows that the format in question is only recognized by newer browsers, which may be the problem here. He neglects to show mobile browsers on the list

Comment: Might want to check http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx - Note the trailing "Z" at the end of the date "literal".  It would seem you might have to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally said I would go with Date.js, but a bit of Googling showed that it hasn't had a commit since 2007, and was riddled with bugs. In addition, it just didn't work quite right.

As of right now, I got tired of looking for a proper solution and got it working with the following Javascript code in **Step 3**.

```
function parseDate(date){
    var year = parseInt(date.substring(0,4));
    var month = parseInt(date.substring(5,7));
    var day = parseInt(date.substring(8,10));
    var hour = parseInt(date.substring(11,13));
    var minute = parseInt(date.substring(14,16));
    var second = parseInt(date.substring(17,19));
    return new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
}

for(i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    var date = Date.parse(points[i].EarnedOn);
    ...
```

This is really quite ugly, but it *is an answer*, so I'm putting it here. I really hope someone comes along and finds something more elegant than this.

Answer (score 0):

How about converting the DateTime in .Net to timestamp/seconds. The conversion in JavaScript to date object. I havent tested it on mobile browsers however, so can't be 100% it will work.

```
DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(2012, 01, 17, 9, 30, 0);

long ticks = (myDateTime - DateTime.Parse("01/01/1970 00:00:00")).Ticks;
ticks /= 10000000; //Convert ticks to seconds
var timestamp = ticks.ToString();
```

Then in JavaScript, something like

```
secsToTime = function(theSecs)
{
    var date = new Date(theSecs*1000);
    // hours part from the timestamp

    var hours = date.getHours();
    // minutes part from the timestamp
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    // seconds part from the timestamp
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();

    // will display time in 10:30:23 format
    var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    alert(formattedTime);
}

secsToTime(1326792600);
```

Comment: I like this solution technically, since it leaves no room for misinterpretation, but *where* would I do this? After I get the list from LINQ? I feel silly having to then iterate over that list *again*, but if there's no way to do this in LINQ itself I guess I have no choice

Comment: What is the architecture of the system? Is it EntityFramework? Are you converting your model into a ViewModel before giving it back to the client?

Comment: I am using Entity Framework, but I don't tend to use ViewModels for API JSON requests. Is this a bad practice? You can see pretty much what I do to send the request in **Step 2** of my original post

Comment: It depends on the requirements really, for example you may have sensitive data that you can't transmit to the client. Normally I project into ViewModels using AutoMapper to cut the amount of data down that goes to the client. Or if you want to leave it as is have an extra property in your model (and not mapped to EF) that is a string for the time in seconds and update that using the loop and use that for the client.